# PHP if condition page redirection

Tags: php

Using the following condition for redirecting users to login.php is not working.

```
<?php 
if(userid()=='') {
?>
header ('location: login.php');
```

Output in webpage is displayed like `header ('location: login.php');` and no redirection is happening.

Sorry i am new to PHP please help me out if i am wrong.

Comment: You're closing the `php` tag too soon. Put `?>` after the `header` command

Comment: That's because you closed the php script before `header ('location: login.php');`.

Comment: everything that's PHP code needs to be within the PHP tags `<?php /*your code*/ ?>`

Answer (score 4):

Simple Typo:

Change to:

```
<?php 
if(userid()=='') {
    header ('location: login.php');
    exit();
    // Your code.
}
?>
```

**PHP**, **JavaScript** and **HTML** codes can be embedded in each other without hassle in **PHP file**.

But, PHP code must be enclosed within `<?php` and `?>` OR  `<?` and `?>`

JavaScript code must be enclosed within `<script>` and `</script>`.

Any code that is not enclosed within above two is considered as **Plain HTML**.

Comment: close the curly braces?

Comment: I think it's worth noting that calling `exit()` after your `header(...)` call is a good idea, as otherwise PHP will happily continue processing whatever else might be part of that particular script.

Comment: @kungphu To avoid having to do that, you can put the rest of your code in an `else`-clause instead.

Comment: And only one dubble quote?

Comment: @klaar I'd call that a matter of preference; I personally would rather explicitly call `exit()` than have to wrap the entire rest of my script in an otherwise-unnecessary conditional. Either, though, is valid (unless your script has been included as part of another, in which case this suggestion won't effectively stop execution).

Comment: Hi all, have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: @kungphu That is indeed a matter of preference, because I'd like to see at a glance that code is only executed if a condition has (or not) been fullfilled. If it's not within braces, I'd assume that it will run no matter what. I don't like exit statements that you explicitly have to look for to know they are there; as for an if-else with curly braces you can see at a glance that it is subject to condition testing. But again, that's personal.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP syntax is not correct:

```
<?php 
   if(userid()=='') {

     header ('Location: login.php'); //header should be within if loop

   } //you missing closing brace

?>
```

Learn the basic of [PHP condition](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Answer (score 1):

The right Syntax would be:

```
header( "Location: login.php" ); die;
```

You also forgot to close the { in your if statement, so you have to add it after the statement above

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php   if(userid()=='') {

 header ('Location: login.php');  exit();   }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Change this

```
<?php 
if(!userid()) {
header ('location: login.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: close the curly braces?

Comment: You should always use `exit;` after a header call to make sure the script stops processing.

Answer (score 0):

Solution-1

start php tag

if( userid()=='' )  {

header ('location: login.php');

}

end php tag

Solution-2

Omit the ending php tag (?>) in any php file.

start php tag

if( userid()=='' ) {

header ('location: login.php');

}

do not end php tag

Comment: You should always use `exit;` after a header call to make sure the script stops processing.